# How do I efficiently generate a list of primes in Perl 6?

Tags: primes, raku

Generating a list of primes is incredibly easy in Perl 6 using [`is-prime`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/is-prime):

```
my @primes = (^∞).grep: *.is-prime;
```

This works well enough if you need a relatively small number of primes, but is very inefficient for large numbers, since every number is independently checked.

Is there a way to access Perl 6's built-in prime checking logic to efficiently create a list of primes?
Otherwise I'll need to build a sieve myself.  Easy enough, but I'm afraid a sieve in high-level Perl 6 code will be almost as inefficient as the code I started with.

Comment: It's worth noting Perl 6's `is-prime` routine [is probabilistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)

Comment: Doh, must check in branch with much faster is-prime (that is also deterministic for 64-bit inputs).  You could also write a Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: @DanaJ: yeah, you promised us that quite some time ago  :-)  No pressure!

Comment: @Zoffix: good point; so my idea of “borrowing” the code to get a list of primes more efficiently, doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @DanaJ: a much faster is-prime, that sounds awesome.  Too bad it missed the recent Rakudo release, now it won't be in Rakudo Star until 2014.07.  

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote some Perl 6 bindings for [primesieve](http://primesieve.org):

https://github.com/CurtTilmes/perl6-primesieve

Math::Primesieve

Comment: Nice!  I added it to my benchmarks, and it destroys all other versions – including cheating (= reading primes from a text file)!  That might partially be because I'm just returning the whole list of primes instead of using a lazy list like in the other versions.  Enhancement request: it'd be awesome if you could also expose `primesieve::iterator`.

Comment: The default libprimesieve does include an iterator, and I started adding it, but the main function is defined in the header file as a 'static inline' function.  That makes it fast, but the symbol doesn't go into the library and I can't call it directly with Nativecall.  I would have to build a custom version of the library that compiles that function as a callable library symbol.

Comment: That's too bad.  Still, if you know in advance how many primes you need (or have a reasonable upper limit at least), Math::Primesieve is unbeatable!

Comment: Beating file I/O isn't too hard, but primesieve goes beyond that.  It's the fastest C code by a fair margin barring yafu's internal sieve (which is pretty close but also not really usable outside of that program).  Kudos for the Perl6 bindings!

Comment: I see that Math::Primesieve is now listed on [modules.perl6.org](https://modules.perl6.org) and can be simply installed with `zef install Math::Primesieve`.  Nice!  Thanks, @Curt!

Comment: @mscha -- Try it now.  I think I got the iterator working.

Comment: @curt – Neat!  Unfortunately, the iterator dumps core on my machine.  See https://github.com/CurtTilmes/perl6-primesieve/issues/3 .

Comment: And the core dump has been fixed!  Math::Primesieve::iterator added to the script in my benchmark answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you run your program with `--profile`, you will see that more than 99% of the time is spent in `Int.is-prime`.  Since that effectively is just a wrapper around `nqp::isprime_I()`, I have tried to run similar code without the wrapper.  But that doesn't change anything noticeably.  So the brunt of the work is being done in `nqp::isprime_I()`.

So the only option you really have is to parallelize your searches for primes.  In the (nearer) future, `hyper` would be your friend here.  But that is currently at the "initial naive implementation" phase, with a more robust implementation being discussed in: https://gist.github.com/jnthn/6a80a9712fb38b32537f9f0e46fca6d7

Until then, if you want to run things faster, you would have to manually break up the range of values you want to check for primedness and run them within a `start` block, and collect the results from the resulting `Promise`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  It wasn't quite what I was looking for, though; I wanted to use the internal code to prevent checking one-by-one.  But I learned from @Zoffix that that won't be possible, since the internal code doesn't do a sieve or something similar, but a primality test.  That will always be too inefficient to generate a list of primes.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really an answer to my question, but I benchmarked a few ways to get a list of primes.

Conclusions:

1. .is-prime is indeed way too slow for this (although @DanaJ's branch hopefully improves this a bit).
2. A sieve in Perl 6 code isn't as slow as I feared, as long as you optimize things a bit (i.e. make the code less pretty Perl6ish).
3. Native code (by way of a Perl 5 module) is still way faster.
4. Cheating is the fastest.

**Edit:** added Curt Tilmes' Primesieve module.  Wow, it's fast!  It beats cheating (i.e. reading primes from a file)!
Well, that might be because Primesieve doesn't support a generator/iterator (yet?), so I'm just returning the whole list at once, while all other versions use a generator / lazy list.

**Edit:** added “even more optimized” sieve based on Timbus' comment.  This one has a pretty decent performance, but the code is almost impossible to follow...

**Edit:** added an even better pure Perl6 version with a flexible sieve size.  I start with a (pre-initialized) sieve for the odd numbers 1..99, and double the sieve size as necessary.  Together with some further optimizations (e.g. when extending the sieve, we only have to check primes up to √(sieve size)) this is by far the fastest pure Perl 6 version so far.  Further advantages: you don't have to know a limit in advance; and it gives the small primes a lot faster if you do need a high limit.

**Edit:** Math::Primesieve now supports an iterator, so include that in the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.c;

# The easy but slow way
sub primes-is-prime
{
    (^∞).grep: *.is-prime;
}

# Use a sieve (simple Perl 6 style)
sub primes-sieve(Int $max)
{
    my @sieve;
    lazy gather for 2..$max -> $p {
        next if @sieve[$p];
        take $p;
        for 2*$p, 3*$p ... $max -> $n {
            @sieve[$n] = True;
        }
    }
}

# Use a sieve (optimized)
sub primes-sieve2(Int $max)
{
    my int @sieve;
    lazy gather {
        take 2;
        loop (my int $p = 3; $p ≤ $max; $p += 2) {
            next if @sieve[$p];
            take $p;
            loop (my int $n = 3*$p; $n ≤ $max; $n += 2*$p) {
                @sieve[$n] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

# Use a sieve (even more optimized)
sub primes-sieve3(Int $max)
{
    my int @sieve;
    my $max2 = ($max-1) div 2;
    lazy gather {
        take 2;
        for 1 .. $max2 -> int $i {
            next if @sieve[$i];
            take 2*$i + 1;
            my $max3 = ($max2 - $i) div (2*$i + 1);
            for 1 .. $max3 -> int $j {
                @sieve[(2*$j + 1)*$i + $j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

# Use a flexible sieve size (and further optimized)
sub primes-sieve4
{
    # Pre-initialize our sieve with the odd numbers from 1 to 99
    my $max = 100;
    my int @sieve = 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,
                    1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1;

    lazy gather {
        # Don't forget our single even prime number
        take 2;

        my int $min-i = 1;
        loop {
            # Take all primes in the new part of the sieve 
            my int $max-i = ($max-1) div 2;
            for $min-i .. $max-i -> int $i {
                take 2*$i + 1 unless @sieve[$i];
            }

            # Extend sieve by factor 2
            # We must check the primes from 3 to √(2*max) in the sieve
            # for max to 2*max
            for 1 .. ((2*$max).sqrt.floor-1) div 2 -> int $i {
                next if @sieve[$i];
                my int $p = 2*$i + 1;
                my int $min-j = max(($max-i - $i) div $p, $i);
                my int $max-j = (2*$max-i + 1 - $i) div $p;
                for $min-j .. $max-j -> int $j {
                    @sieve[$i + $p*$j] = 1;
                }
            }

            # Double the sieve size, and start the next iteration
            # in the second half of the sieve
            $max *= 2;
            $min-i = $max-i+1;
        }
    }
}

# Use a Perl 5 module
sub primes-perl5
{
    use Math::Prime::Util:from<Perl5> <prime_iterator>;

    my $it = prime_iterator;
    lazy gather {
        loop {
            take $it.();
        }
    }
}

# Use Primesieve module
sub primes-primesieve($max)
{
    # See:
    #  - http://primesieve.org/
    #  - https://github.com/CurtTilmes/perl6-primesieve
    use Math::Primesieve;

    # No iterator support (yet?), so just return the whole list
    return Math::Primesieve.new.primes($max);
}

# Use Primesieve module (iterator)
sub primes-primesieve-iterator
{
    # See:
    #  - http://primesieve.org/
    #  - https://github.com/CurtTilmes/perl6-primesieve
    use Math::Primesieve;
    my $iterator = Math::Primesieve::iterator.new;
    lazy gather {
        loop {
            take $iterator.next;
        }
    }
}

# Cheat
# Source: https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/ - first million
# (Unzip and remove the first few lines from the file.)
sub primes-cheat
{
    lazy $*PROGRAM.sibling('primes1.txt').words.map(+*);
}

sub timer(&code)
{
    my $start = now;
    &code();
    my $elapsed = now - $start;
    say "Elapsed: $elapsed.fmt('%.3f')s";
}

sub MAIN
{
    #my $nth = 1_000;
    #my $max = 8_000;

    #my $nth = 10_000;
    #my $max = 105_000;

    my $nth = 50_000;
    my $max = 612_000;

    timer {
        my @primes = primes-is-prime;
        say "Using .is-prime: @primes[$nth]";
    }
    timer {
        my @primes = primes-sieve($max);
        say "Using a sieve (simple Perl 6 style): @primes[$nth]";
    }
    timer {
        my @primes = primes-sieve2($max);
        say "Using a sieve (optimized): @primes[$nth]";
    }
    timer {
        my @primes = primes-sieve3($max);
        say "Using a sieve (even more optimized): @primes[$nth]";
    }
    timer {
        my @primes = primes-sieve4;
        say "Using a flexible sieve size (further optimized): @primes[$nth]";
    }
    timer {
        my @primes = primes-perl5;
        say "Using a Perl 5 module: @primes[$nth]";
    }
    timer {
        my @primes = primes-primesieve($max);
        say "Using Primesieve module: @primes[$nth]";
    }
    timer {
        my @primes = primes-primesieve-iterator;
        say "Using Primesieve module (iterator): @primes[$nth]";
    }
    timer {
        my @primes = primes-cheat;
        say "Cheating: @primes[$nth]";
    }
}

# 4 year old Linux server, running Rakudo Star 2017.04:
#
# Using .is-prime: 611957
# Elapsed: 216.134s
# Using a sieve (simple Perl 6 style): 611957
# Elapsed: 124.087s
# Using a sieve (optimized): 611957
# Elapsed: 41.129s
# Using a sieve (even more optimized): 611957
# Elapsed: 7.285s
# Using a flexible sieve size (further optimized): 611957
# Elapsed: 3.897s
# Using a Perl 5 module: 611957
# Elapsed: 10.031s
# Using Primesieve module: 611957
# Elapsed: 0.312s
# Using Primesieve module (iterator): 611957
# Elapsed: 1.460s
# Cheating: 611957
# Elapsed: 2.017s
```

Comment: Interesting.. An extra note: replacing both the `primes-sieve2` `loop`s with `for 2..$max/2 -> $x { my $p = $x*2+1; ... }` (same effective loop count) gives a measurable performance increase (from 13.0s to 7.8s for me).. Looks even more ugly but there ya go.

Comment: Good one, @Timbus.  When I tried it, it saved a little, but not as much as it did for you.  But when I did a similar thing to the inner loop, it saved a *lot* of time!  (I also optimized the sieve usage: use it only for odd numbers, so it's half the size.)

Comment: And I just realized that's what you were doing as well (“replacing both the primes-sieve2 loops”).

Comment: Yup, but you made it faster by halving the array. Also here's an attempt at making the code more legible: https://gist.github.com/TiMBuS/2965b4f3c5ff29c165b56a13f2fbc668